# Unable to see the cells in the Excel workbook

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vba, macros, microsoft-excel-2016

I am unable to understand this worksheet which was written by someone else. There are certain columns which are not visible unless activated. This activation occurs when I change a value in particular cell. I am unable to understand how it works.

[Example 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NUThO.png)

[Example 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GLsaY.png)

There are no macros or VBAs active in this file. Please help me. Thank you in advance.

Comment: You can select the problem cells and check if there are formulas for these cells. Or under *Formula* tab check *Show formulas*, *Trace Precedents*, *Trace Dependents* options: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0h6PV.png

Comment: There are formulas for some cells, some cells are just numeric. It just they do not appear until certain threshold has reached in the input cell. How can visibility be detected based on the an input threshold? The values are present in the cell just not visible until threshold has reached.

Comment: Your question is hard to understand, and your example images don’t illustrate the problem.  Please give a better explanation of what you see, and then, optionally, add image(s) that show that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Such visual stylings are possible either by using `Conditional Formatting` or by using a `Cell Format`/`Number Format`.

## Conditional Formatting

Via: `"HOME" -> "Styles" -> "Conditional Formatting"`

With `Conditional Formatting` you can apply different types of formats to cells, when they or any other cell meet a certain condition.

There are some predefined styles from Microsoft available, but you can always create a custom one using a custom formula.

If you want to see which conditional formattings are used in a particular worksheet:

1. Click the `Conditional Formatting` button in the ribbon tab "Home"
2. Select `Manage Rules..`
3. Change the selection of `Show Formatting Rules for` to `This Worksheet`

**With such styling options you can apply a white font color to hide values.**

> `Conditional Formatting` also allows us to set a `Number Format/Cell Format` which is explained in the next topic.

### More information

- Use conditional formatting to highlight information
  https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/use-conditional-formatting-to-highlight-information-fed60dfa-1d3f-4e13-9ecb-f1951ff89d7f

## Number Format / Cell Format

Via: `<Right Click on Cell> -> "Format Cells ..."`

With a `Number Format`, which is not limited to numbers, you can apply formats and even add text or fill the cell with a certain characters.

The are some predefined styles for different types of data, but you can always use your custom format.

The custom formats by default follows this notation *(each format is delimited by a semi-colon)*:

> *<Format for positive values>***;***<Format for negative values>***;***<Format for 0>***;***<Format for Text>*`

If you omit a format in the notation, the number (or text) will not be shown, but is still available for other formulas or VBA.
**The following format will hide every number which is not positive (including 0) and all text:**

```
0.##;;;
```

If you omit a semi-colon, Excel will apply the defined formats depending on how many formats you have defined.

- If you only define one format `00000`, Excel will format all numbers that way, but leaves text untouched.
- If you only define two formats `00;[RED]0`, Excel will format positive and 0 values with `00`, negative values in red, but leaves text untouched.
- If you define three formats `"+";"-";"Zero"`, Excel will format (respectively replace in this case) positive numbers with "+", negative numbers with "-" and 0 with "Zero", but leaves text untouched.

### Example for a conditional format

The following example does not follow the default process, since we are using our own conditions like `[>=1]`.

```
[Blue][>=1]*.0.0#" (HIGH)";[>0]0.0#*." (MID)";*.0.0#" (LOW)"*.;@" (TEXT)"
```

This formats

- numbers greater than or equal to 1 in blue, prefixed with dots to fill the entire cell and the text "(HIGH)"
- numbers greater than 0 suffixed with dots to fill the entire cell and the text "(MID)"
- numbers, which don't meet the above two conditions prefixed with dots to fill the entire cell and the text "(LOW)"
- text with the text "(TEXT)"

### More information

- Available number formats in Excel
  https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/available-number-formats-in-excel-0afe8f52-97db-41f1-b972-4b46e9f1e8d2
- Review guidelines for customizing a number format
  https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/review-guidelines-for-customizing-a-number-format-c0a1d1fa-d3f4-4018-96b7-9c9354dd99f5
- Conditional Number Formatting
  https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/excel-blog/conditional-number-formatting/ba-p/850068

Comment: It was conditional formatting after all! Thank you so much for helping me out.